Libvirt bridging used to work, now it doesnt. Layer 2 does though, but nothing else
Ive had this problem before but no idea what I did to make it go away, but the effect is no Layer 3 or above connectivity on my VMs.
The host isn't using NetworkManager or anything fancy... just /etc/network interfaces where I created a bridge, and that bridge has the OS's vlan upstream interface enp0s31f6.402 for this particular routed network as  a member:
# brctl show br402
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br402       8000.32084a26cf98   no      enp0s31f6.402
                            vnet8
#

And also in libvirt I have a bridge there of the same name br402 and a VM with a virtio nic connected to that libvirtd bridge, which the OS sees there as vnet8 as show above
<network connections="1">
  <name>br402</name>
  <uuid>784ab15b-e3b1-4bce-b2b5-bceb076d4285</uuid>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br402"/>
</network>

In that VM its also all /etc/network/interfaces as well.  Now from the console I have no layer 3 connectivity but I do see arp and layer2 going on it it.
Just earlier tonight it was all 100% solid, all worked fine.  Then I had the great idea to delete the default network in libvirt since nothing I had here used it and I wanted to get it out of the host OS's ifconfig results.  Also just mistakenly rebooted the host as well.
I did restart that default notwork, even rebooted the host.  No help - every single VM on this host now is dead from no connectivity
